# Who is this mysterious guest?

Tags: riddle

Me: Knock, knock!

Friend: You love drawing attention to yourself, don't you?

Me: Can I ask you for a favor?

Friend: Take off your shoes first.

Me: Would you like a beer?

Friend: As if I haven't mentioned that I don't drink over the phone.

Me: Fine, I will type a message.

Friend: You are exhausting me.

Who am I?

HINT 1:

> Me: But your shoulder is so tempting.

HINT 2:

> Friend: Just go back to Lisbon.

HINT 3:

> I am not a person, and I am vaguely a thing.

Comment: You are a psychedelic dream

Comment: @hypeJunction haha I feel this question is good psychology one

Comment: It's a linguistic mind-twister ;)

Comment: I love a riddle that leaves me lost on every line.  Then I hate it.  Then eventually I love it again.

Comment: Please, give us another hint. One question: are you a person, or can you be an object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are

> Tap

Me: Knock, knock!

> Who is that tapping on my chamber door?

Friend: You love drawing attention to yourself, don't you?

> To tap something means to draw from it.

Me: Can I ask you for a favor?

> Tap can mean to obtain money or information from someone.

Friend: Take off your shoes first.

> Tap dancing shoes

Me: Would you like a beer?

> Beer on tap?

Friend: As if I haven't mentioned that I don't drink over the phone.

> To tap a phone means to connect to it so that it can be listened to secretly.

Me: Fine, I will type a message.

> Tap typing.

Friend: You are exhausting me.

> I'm tapped out!

Hint 1

> Tap on the shoulder.

Hint 2

> TAP is a Portuguese airline carrier.

Hint 3

> A tap can be a thing but, in many contexts, it's not a physical thing.

Comment: Well done @hexomino, I've been thinking about this for a lot of time. Now that I see the solution, I can conclude I would have never get it right!

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Siri. You are constantly annoying your owner, suggesting things he doesn't want or need.

Me: Knock, knock!
Friend: You love drawing attention to yourself, don't you?

> The phone gets a message and makes a sound with two short pings, the phone owner is interrupted and dismissive

Me: Can I ask you for a favor?
Friend: Take off your shoes first.

I don't have an explanation for that one, probably something misheard ("conversation" instead of "off your shoes")?

Me: Would you like a beer?
Friend: As if I haven't mentioned that I don't drink over the phone.

> Siri suggests a restaurant or a beer garden, the phone owner didn't want to drink.

Me: Fine, I will type a message.
Friend: You are exhausting me.

> The phone misunderstood the next command as the suggestion to write a new text message, and opened the text message function. The friend is exasperated.

Hint1:

> The phone likes being held on the shoulder for a conversation

Hint2:

> The friend meant "Just go back to listening", telling the phone to shut up

Hint3:

> The AI is certainly too dumb to be mistaken as a person, and being software, it doesn't really qualify as a "thing"

Comment: I am not Siri, but you may meet me on your way to her.

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> A drive assist (system/app)

Me: Knock, knock!

> The app interrupted the silence to draw the driver's attention.

Friend: You love drawing attention to yourself, don't you?

> What do you want, drive assistant?

Me: Can I ask you for a favor?
Friend: Take off your shoes first.

> The drive assist wanted to ask if it could **do** (not **ask**) a favor (sometimes drive assistants spell things wrongly). The driver asked it to first turn down the music (take off your shoes = turn down the music).

Me: Would you like a beer?
Friend: As if I haven't mentioned that I don't drink over the phone.

> Tiresome as these assist are, it keeps asking questions untiringly. The driver reminded the app of his/her preferences. He/She doesn't like beer!!

Me: Fine, I will type a message.
Friend: You are exhausting me.

> The assist app just won't shut up, now it mistakenly understood that the driver wanted to send a message. The assist might have heard "**send** (a message) over the phone" from the previous conversation, instead of "(...)**drink** over the phone".

HINT 1:

> **Me: But your shoulder is so tempting.**
>  Maybe the drive assist app was referring to the seat belt?

HINT 2:

> **Friend: Just go back to Lisbon.**
>  Like saying: you just drive me to Lisbon and stop complimenting me!

Comment: I am too short to be a drive assist app

Comment: Alright but it fits all the conversation and hints!

Comment: Never heard of a knocking car horn

Comment: Alright, modified to make more sense

Comment: As suggested in the other comments I am not really a thing. And this is a linguistic riddle

Comment: Cool, I will keep thinking then